# Logged into a VPN "successfully" but IP address hasn't changed, where am I going wrong?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn

Since I've been using a lot of open wifi connections recently, I've decided to use a VPN. Fortunately my uni has one that I can use for free at `gucsasa1.cent.gla.ac.uk (130.209.15.226)`.

I have connected via the suggested (by the uni) Cisco AnyConnect, and also via an open alternative called OpenConnect. The problem lies in that although through both pieces of software it claims that I have connected successfully without issue, when I use websites to check my IP address or check my location, it still shows just as before.

So I guess I have more than one question:
1) Does the fact that my visible IP address and location stay the same indicate the VPN isn't working?
2) If this fact doesn't indicate anything, can I use any tools (I'm on Linux) to ensure my data is being sent via the VPN?

P.S. I did a traceroute to google.com and can't see `gucsasa1.cent.gla.ac.uk (130.209.15.226)`

```
traceroute to google.com (173.194.41.67), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  38.421 ms  40.489 ms  47.340 ms
 3  192.168.134.2 (192.168.134.2)  50.878 ms  51.077 ms  51.222 ms
 4  192.168.190.251 (192.168.190.251)  51.856 ms  55.291 ms  66.719 ms
 5  192.168.71.20 (192.168.71.20)  66.726 ms  66.840 ms  66.923 ms
 6  192.168.69.252 (192.168.69.252)  75.897 ms  37.961 ms  42.209 ms
 7  217.39.0.2 (217.39.0.2)  42.356 ms  38.955 ms  42.898 ms
 8  213.120.178.41 (213.120.178.41)  42.844 ms  42.742 ms  53.540 ms
 9  acc1-10GigE-0-1-0-6.l-far.21cn-ipp.bt.net (109.159.249.94)  43.948 ms acc1-10GigE-0-0-0-6.l-far.21cn-ipp.bt.net (109.159.249.90)  44.128 ms 109.159.249.64 (109.159.249.64)  44.691 ms
10  core2-te0-0-0-7.faraday.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.249.7)  44.775 ms core1-te0-0-0-6.faraday.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.249.1)  48.468 ms core1-te0-15-0-7.faraday.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.249.37)  49.771 ms
11  peer1-xe8-0-1.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net (109.159.254.175)  50.979 ms  43.961 ms  47.212 ms
12  195.99.126.113 (195.99.126.113)  43.244 ms 195.99.125.25 (195.99.125.25)  43.210 ms 195.99.126.109 (195.99.126.109)  43.342 ms
13  209.85.252.186 (209.85.252.186)  40.685 ms  44.047 ms  44.054 ms
14  72.14.238.51 (72.14.238.51)  45.557 ms  46.068 ms  36.365 ms
15  lhr08s01-in-f3.1e100.net (173.194.41.67)  46.483 ms  44.805 ms  45.066 ms
```

Comment: Just because you create a VPN connection, does not mean you will always route through that connection.  If you want all your traffic to pass through the VPN, you need to set that.  Since I only know how to do this in Windows, I will let a Linux expert answer.

Comment: And since the traffic isn't necessarily passing through the VPN, I may still be insecure? Also, thanks :)